# Como setar os valores de uma PropertyInfo das classes instanciadas dentro de uma classe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflexão

Estou fazendo um método genérico para arredondamento de valores de uma classe(T), porém também tenho as classes dentro dessa principal(T), essas classes eu consigo setar desse modo:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> childrenProperties = entidade.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(model => model.PropertyType.Namespace == typeof(T).Namespace).ToArray();
```

Gostaria de saber como pegar os valores dessas classes, com a classe principal(T) eu simplesmente faço assim:

```
    foreach (var propertie in decimalPropertiesModel)
    {
        var value = propertie.GetValue(entidade, null);

        if (value != null)
        {
            propertie.SetValue(entidade, decimal.Round((decimal)value, noCasasDecimais), null);
        }
    }
```

Mas com as outras classes não consigo do mesmo modo.

Lembrando que isso é um método genérico, tenho a classe principal CentroTrabalhoOnline, consigo setar todas propriedades e seus valores dessa classe, porém dentro dessa classe também tenho a classe CentroTrabalho, quero saber como setar as propriedades e seus valores dessa classe CentroTrabalho.

Comment: Não entendi o problema, está dando erro ou resultado inesperado? Onde você consegue e onde não? O problema não está em outro ponto, ou seja, o que você está recebendo (`decimalPropertiesModel`) neste trecho é que está errado? Posso estar enganado mas não parece haver erro aí.

Comment: "arredondamento de valores de uma classe(T), porém também tenho as classes dentro dessa principal(T)" - não percebi. Mostra uma classes que sirvam como exemplo do input, e mostra o output desejado.

Comment: Como assim "pegar os valores dessas classes"? Que valores são esses? Que classes são essas?

Comment: editei a descrição da pergunta, no final.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi corretamente, você tem uma classe que tem uma mistura de propriedades normais (de `int`, `double`, `decimal`, etc.) e propriedades de classes (de `Class1`, `OutroClasse`, etc.).

Se você quer acessar as propriedades de todas as classes, será necessária criar uma função recursiva. Não tenho exatamente como seria, mas use o código seguinte para te inspirar:

```
public void Recursiva(Type tipo, object entidade) {
    foreach ( prop in entidade.GetType().GetProperties() ) {
       var value = prop.GetValue( entidade, null );
       if ( value is decimal ) {
          //faz algo com decimal
       } else {
          //chama o Recursiva de novo:
          Recursive(value.GetType(), value );
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Legal @brazilianldsjaguar, realmente é por esse caminho, vou ver se consigo implementar algo assim e retorno quando possível, ta meio corrido aqui rs, abraços !!